# populate a datagrid using string for a for loop

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, wpfdatagrid, telerik-grid

I am trying to populate the datagrid below using this loop, but i am not sure how to populate it using variables. The loop below is only a sample of my code; can someone show me how to populate this data grid. Also this is a windows store app.

```
  for (var index = 1; index < tsTable.ChildNodes.Count; index++)
  {
       var row = tsTable.ChildNodes[index];

        if ((index > 2) && row.InnerHtml != "\n")
        {

          var transactionLink = row.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes["a"].Attributes["href"].Value;
          var blookLink = row.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes["a"].Attributes["href"].Value;
        }
   }
```

```
  <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="RadDataGridTest" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"           AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.GroupDescriptors>
                    <telerikGrid:PropertyGroupDescriptor PropertyName="Group"/>
                </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.GroupDescriptors>
                <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
                    <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="dgTransactionLink" Header="Transaction Link"/>
                    <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="dgBlookLink" Header="Blook Link/>
                <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
  </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
```

Comment: If you note that the `ItemsSource` for the grid is a property named `Data`. If `Data` is an `ObservableCollection` (as it should be), then you can just add whatever contents you want to it, including strings. Something like `Data.Add(transactionLink)` or something.